Paquetes SSIS no se detienen al tener un error
Buen dia con todos,
Estoy desarrollando un SSIS en visual studio 2017(soy nuevo en creaciones de ssis) y mi paquete funciona bien pero justo queriendo validar los envios de correo cuando pase un error  me he dado cuenta de esto.

como puedo hacer para que si en un paquete sale error que se detenga.
Muchas gracias :)

Puse en tru a estos parametros de mi contenedor y me funciono


¿Qué son estos parámetros? Ten presente que no todos pueden ver las imágenes. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu respuesta.
